# jQuery chaining of getting html and replaceWith

Tags: jquery, chaining

I'm using jQuery to get the content of a link and want to replace the link with just the content it has.

I got it to work, but I'm wondering if I could write it in just **one** statement instead of two.

Here is my code:

```
text = $(this).closest('.ui-btn-text').find("a[data-rel='popup']").html();
$(this).closest('.ui-btn-text').find("a[data-rel='popup']").replaceWith(text);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.replaceWith()` function accepts a function which returns the new HTML to replace that element with, so you could do:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-btn-text').find("a[data-rel='popup']").replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

It's important to note that `this` inside the function passed to `.replaceWith()` is different to `this` at the beginning of the line; inside the function it refers to the current matched element being replaced by the new HTML.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you also for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize it like

```
textObj = $(this).closest('.ui-btn-text').find("a[data-rel='popup']");
textObj.replaceWith(textObj.html());
```

Comment: Sorry typo, it should be textObj

Comment: While this is correct, the OP is looking for how to do this in one statement, not two.

Comment: This solution has 7 less characters than Anthonys, you could just put it on one line :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = $(this).closest('.ui-btn-text').find("a[data-rel='popup']");
node.replaceWith(node.html());
```